# Django Return a Download and Redirect to a Different page

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am setting up a site where as a user I can assign something to someone and anytime it is assigned a new PDF document is created. Currently the user would just go to the users account page, click on the assign page, and fill out the form. Once this form is submitted a document(pdf) is created and saved with the model that is created and the user is redirected to the account page they were just at. Here they can click on what has been assigned to download the document that was created. However, I want to have it be that once submitted they get redirected back to the account page and also starts the download. I was thinking of just making a get request using requests but I read that is not a good approach. Below is the code I have for the download as well as the code for the view submit.

**Download View**

```
@login_required
def attendance_download(request, employee_id, attendance_id):
    employee = Employee.objects.get(employee_id=employee_id)
    attendance = Attendance.objects.get(id=attendance_id)
    pretty_filename = f'{employee.first_name} {employee.last_name} Attendance Point.pdf'

    try:
        with open(attendance.document.path, 'rb') as f:
            response = HttpResponse(f, content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment;filename="{pretty_filename}"'

            return response
    except:
        messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, 'No File to Download')

        return redirect('employee-account', employee_id)
```

**Form View**

```
employee = Employee.objects.get(employee_id=employee_id)
    if request.method == 'GET':

        a_form = AssignAttendance()

        data = {
            'a_form': a_form,
            'employee': employee
        }

        return render(request, 'employees/assign_attendance.html', data)
    else:
        a_form = AssignAttendance(request.POST)

        if a_form.is_valid():
            employee_name = f'{employee.first_name} {employee.last_name}'
            incident_date = a_form.cleaned_data['incident_date'].strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
            reason = a_form.cleaned_data['reason']
            reported_by = f'{request.user.first_name} {request.user.last_name}'

            # This has been ordered to match the document
            history = {
                '0': 0,
                '6': 0,
                '7': 0,
                '2': 0,
                '4': 0,
                '5': 0,
                '3': 0,
            }

            exemption = a_form.cleaned_data['exemption']

            attendance_records = Attendance.objects.filter(employee=employee)

            # Goes through each of the past attendance points and adds +1 to the history ignoring '1'(Consecutive) and
            # treating '8'(Late Lunch) as '6'(< 15min)
            for attendance_record in attendance_records:
                if attendance_record.reason != '1':
                    if attendance_record.reason == '8':
                        history['6'] += 1
                    else:
                        history[attendance_record.reason] += 1

            counseling = counseling_required(employee, reason, exemption)

            document = create_attendance_document(employee_name, incident_date, reason, reported_by, history, exemption, counseling)
            a_form.save(employee, request, document, counseling)

            messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'Attendance Point Successfully Assigned')

            return redirect('employee-account', employee_id=employee_id, download_type='attendance')
        else:
            data = {
                'a_form': a_form,
                'employee': employee
            }

            return render(request, 'employees/assign_attendance.html', data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single HTTP response only can trigger one of those things. My approach would be to redirect to the form view and pass an special argument the time you want the file to be downloaded, and then trigger that download in the browser using Javascript:

```
window.onload = function(e){ 
    window.location.href = '{{your_file_url}}';
}
```

Comment: So if there is a url set to ```window.location.href``` the file will start downloading immediately?

Comment: Yes, it has the same effect as clicking in a link to that URL.

Comment: Perfect, I will give it a try in the morning. If it works I will accept your answer